# How to load only 50 records at a time into a table using SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl

I have an excel sheet with a record of 6471 rows of data I need to load only 50 records at a time can anyone help me out here

Comment: Ok so you loaded 50 what's the criterion for loading the next 50?

Comment: There are no criteria I just need to load 50 records per batch of execution

Comment: You can also control the import by adding a range to your request. Example: "Select * from [SheetName$A1:G51]"

Answer (score 0):

I will use a script task to read the excel sheet into a data table, then read the first 50 rows of that data table.
I added some code snippet that may guide you.

1. Read excel into a data table

   ```
   using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection xlConn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        xlConn.Open();
                        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand xlCmd = xlConn.CreateCommand();
                        xlCmd.CommandText = "Select * from [" + ExcelTable + "$]";
                        xlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader rdr = xlCmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (rdr.Read())
                            {
                                sRow = stagingTable.NewRow();// tAble.NewRow();
                                for (int i = 1; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++) 
                                {
                                    if (!HeadersCreated)
                                    {
                                        sCol = new DataColumn();
                                        sCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
                                        sCol.ColumnName = "Col" + i.ToString();
                                        stagingTable.Columns.Add(sCol);
                                    }
                                    {
                                        sRow["Col" + i.ToString()] = rdr[i].ToString();
                                    }
                                }
                                stagingTable.Rows.Add(sRow);
                                HeadersCreated = true;
                            }
                        }
                        xlConn.Close();
                    }
   ```
2. read first 50 rows of data table

   ```
          for (int i = 0; i < stagingTable.Rows.Count || i <= 50; i++)
        {
                for (int j =0; j < stagingTable.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stagingTable.Rows[0][j].ToString()))
                    {
                        sRow = tAble.NewRow();
                        sRow["col1"] = DepartmentName.ToString();
                        sRow["col2"] = stagingTable.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                        sRow["col3"] = stagingTable.Rows[i][j].ToString();
                        sRow["col4"] = stagingTable.Rows[0][j].ToString();
                        tAble.Rows.Add(sRow);
                    }
                }

            }
   ```
3. Do what you want with the first 50 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure why you want to reduce the rows per batch but you can define that in the destination component as follows:

[image: OLE DB Dest]